# How to fix "Duplicate method name: invalid override of property change signal or superclass signal"?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

On Qt 5.15.1 I want to connect to the [`objectNameChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qtobject.html#objectName-prop) signal of a QML `Item` using [`Connections`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    visible: true

    Item {
        id: foo
    }

    Connections {
        target: foo

//      onObjectNameChanged: console.log(foo.objectName) // old syntax, causes "Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated."
        function onObjectNameChanged() {
            console.log(foo.objectName)
        }
    }
}
```

The code produces the following error:

> Duplicate method name: invalid override of property change signal or superclass signal

I can of course write it like this:

```
Item {
    id: foo

    onObjectNameChanged: console.log(foo.objectName)
}
```

but I need to use `Connections`.

How to fix this?

Comment: The cause of the error is easy to explain: Connections is also a QObject so it also has the objectName property (and the associated signal) and when mapping the objectName property of the target it generates the problem, I don't think there is a workaround so that I recommend you report the bug

Comment: Wow this is very insightful! Indeed, it is easy to explain, but not so obvious to find - I've failed to do so. Your comment would make a great answer. Please add it as such!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my comment:

The cause of the error is easy to explain: Connections is also a QObject so it also has the objectName property (and the associated signal) and when mapping the objectName property of the target it generates the problem, I don't think there is a workaround so that I recommend you report the bug.